# how to match entries from one dataframe to another based on a condition

Tags: dataframe, dplyr, filter, conditional-statements, pattern-matching

I have two dataframe:

```
value <- structure(list(rf1 = c(40000L, 9680000L, 9680000L), rt1 = c(80000L, 
9720000L, 9720000L), rf2 = c(9400000L, 44480000L, 80000L), rt2 = c(9440000, 
444520000, 120000)), row.names = c(235L, 1112L, 2L), class = "data.frame")

regions <- structure(list(V2 = c(8522360L, 8591167L, 8791167L, 43059890L, 
43099890L), V3 = c(8551167L, 8631167L, 8831167L, 43099890L, 43139890L
), start = c("9400000", "9480000", "9680000", "44480000", "44520000"
), end = c("9440000", "9520000", "9720000", "44520000", "44560000"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 782L, 783L
))
```

I want to match the first dataframe with second dataframe. Basically if start and end matched with rf2,rt2(together) then rf2 and rt2 gets the value V2 and V3.
Simultaneously, if rf1 and rt1 (together) matched both start and end then rf1 and rt1 get V2 and V3 values. If not, then delete the row, so if (rf1 and rt1) doesn't match delete the row, if (rf2 and rt2) doesn't match delete the row.

So:

```
first dataset: 
rf1 rt1 rf2 rt2 
40000 80000 9400000 9440000
9680000 9720000 44480000 444520000
9680000 9720000 80000 120000

Second dataset: 
V2 V3 start end
522360 8551167 9400000 9440000
8791167 8831167 9680000 9720000
43059890 43099890 44480000 44520000

Selected rows:
9680000 9720000 44480000 444520000
```

It will have only 2nd row since in 1st row (rf1 and rt1) doesn't match even though rf2 and rt2 match with start and end
For 3rd row: will be deleted since (rf1 and rt1) exact match with start and end but (rf2 and rt2) doesn't exactly match with start and end.
For row 2nd: both (rf1 and rt1)  and (rf2 and rt2) exact match with start and end.
Once this row matched: now reassign the values:

```
Final output: 
8791167 8831167 43059890 43099890
```

#match rf2 and rt2 region with region file: if not match remove the row

```
for(i in 1:dim(value)[1]){
  value1 <- region %>% filter((as.numeric(region$start)-1) %in% value$rf2[i],(as.numeric(region$end) %in% value$rt2[i] ))
  if(dim(value1)[1]>=1){
    ##now assign the value:
    value$rf2[i] <- value1$V2
    value$rt2[i] <- value1$V3
  }
    else{
      value <- value[-c(i),]
    }
  }
  


##match rf1 and rt1 with region file: if not match remove the row:

for(i in 1:dim(value)[1]){
  value1 <- region %>% filter((as.numeric(region$start)-1) %in% value$rf1[i],(as.numeric(region$end) %in% value$rt1[i] ))
  if(nrow(value1)>0){
    ##now assign the value:
    value$rf2[i] <- value1$V2
    value$rt2[i] <- value1$V3
  }
    else{
      value <- value[-c(i),]
    }
  }
```

In my case: certain values are getting matched but the unmatched values still remains.
Is there any other way to solve this. I will appreciate guidance on how to solve this problem.

Comment: just to clarify Rhea, when you say "start and end matched with rf2,rt2(together)" do you mean `start = rf2`, `end  = rt2`, or that start is either rf2 or rt2, and likewise end?

Comment: Hello, it means start will always be rf2 and end will be rt2. similarly start will always be rf1 and end will be rt1. basically rf means from region and rt means to region.

Comment: I posted a provisional answer. I don't think it's anywhere near a final answer, but maybe a good place to start

Comment: the part I don't understand is, joining on `start = rf2`, `end  = rt2` gives you precisely zero rows?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like based on the description you're wanting something like this:

```
# the start and end columns need to be numeric
regions <- mutate(regions, across(c(start, end), as.numeric))
    
bind_rows(inner_join(regions, value, by = c("start" = "rf1", "end" = "rt2")),
          inner_join(regions, value, by = c("start" = "rf2", "end" = "rt2"))) %>%
        mutate(rf2 = V2, 
               rt2 = V3)

       V2      V3   start     end   rt1     rf2   rf1     rt2
1 8522360 8551167 9400000 9440000 80000 8522360 40000 8551167
```

For more information on joins in R, see [the chapter on joins from the R for Data Science textbook](https://r4ds.hadley.nz/joins.html)

Update:

```
# rf1 and rt1) matches with start and end then update rf1 and rt1 with V2 and V3 simultaneously
m1 <- inner_join(regions, value, by = c("start" = "rf1", "end" = "rt1")) %>%
    mutate(rf1 = V2, 
           rt1 = V3)

#(rf2 and rt2) matches with start and end then update the rf2 and rt2 with start and end
m2 <- inner_join(regions, value, by = c("start" = "rf2", "end" = "rt2")) %>%
    mutate(rf2 = start, 
               rt2 = end)
```

Comment: Hello, I want to match the region. So if (rf1 exactly match with start and rt1 exactly match with end and rf2 exactly match with start and rt2 exactly match with end then keep that entire row, else if any row in which either(rf1 rt1) or (rf2 rt2) doesn't match with start end, remove that row

Comment: okay so in the example, can you find a row where rf1 matches with start?

Comment: Hello, in my example 2nd and 3rd row rf1 matched with start. In my code we need to do -1 from start to match the values. since start values get +1 from previous analysis. that why need to do -1 and then see the matching.

Comment: this is what i did (as.numeric(region$start)-1) %in% value$rf1[i]

Comment: but you're subtracting one from it 

Comment: okay, so the input is bad is what you're saying.

Comment: can you clean the inputs and get them all ready for joining and then edit your question to replace the `dput`s at the top with the cleaned data?

Comment: sure, let me do that.

Comment: I've updated the code. Let me know what you think

Comment: @Mark We started a dialog on a now-deleted question. So I guess I'm stalking you,,,, sorry. I upvoted this answer here because it was answering a well-formed question and is therefore "useful" even if it might be a duplicate which seems possible, but I haven't really looked at it carefully so it may be unique. There are several classes of questions that are many times over duplicates that annoy the heck out of long time answerers: Date format questions in R are one such class of question. Regex pattern construction questions are another such class. You might try reviewing Meta discussions.

Comment: @IRTFM thank you for your reply and engaging with me. The thing is, I could probably see arguments either way for this- the OP was basically asking for an inner join, but the data was messy and it was only after a dozen or so comments and an attempt at an answer that that was clear. I can understand why seeing the same thing over and over would be really frustrating though! Thanks for the suggestion for meta discussions too - I'll have a search through (and if not, maybe post something)

Comment: @IRTFM I did a search and came back with this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions

Comment: Hello, mark it still doesn''t give me expected answers. it updates rf2 and rt2 with V2 and V3 but rf1 and rt1 remains the same, my answer should be if(rf1 and rt1) matches with start and end then update rf1 and rt1 with V2 and V3 simultaneously if (rf2 and rt2) matches with start and end then update the rf2 and rt2 with start and end. in this case only rf2 and rt2 gets updated.

Comment: okay I've updated it. This is the last I'm going to do with this. You know how joins work in R now, or at least you ought to. I'm not going to continue to spoonfeed you code.